# C++ map iterator problem

Tags: c++, iterator

why is this code problematic(in visual studio 2010)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    map<string,int> map;
    map<string,int>::iterator iter = map.begin();
}
```

it just tells me there is a problem in the iterator definition(argument list for class template "std::iterator" is missing), but I saw samples written that way.

Comment: Can you please paste the _exact_ error message that you're getting?

Comment: Maybe because you're using `map` as the variable name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You called your variable `map` and you used `using namespace std;` which will result in name lookup issues as you are using a variable and a library container called the same thing. David in the comments and below explains that portion more.

You can do several things (and there are more you can do beyond these):

1. Qualify your variable declarations with `std::`

   `std::map<string, int> map;`

   `std::map<string, int>::iterator iter = map.begin();`
2. Drop the `using namespace std;` and qualify everything with `std::`
3. Rename your `map` variable. Really, you should probably avoid using library defined names for your variable names.

edit: [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159091/c-map-iterator-problem/5159150#5159150) also should work for you as well.

Comment: Technically `std::map` is not in the global namespace, but rather, the lookup algorithm will add the `std` namespace to the search set *after* processing the global namespace. The difference is most notable if the same identifier appears in more than one namespace: `namespace A { void foo( int ) {} } namespace B { using namespace A; void foo( double ) {} } int main() { using namespace B; foo( 1 ); }` will call `B::foo( double )` and not `A::foo( int )` even if the later is a better match.

Answer (score 6):

Hmmm, I wonder if the compiler would be happy with:

```
typedef map<string,int> MapType;
MapType myMap;
MapType::iterator iter = myMap.begin();
```

I would gravitate towards this anyway as it reduces [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) and looks cleaner to me.

Also the variable name `map` might be confusing the compiler, and at the very least could confuse a human reading the code, so I would change that.

Comment: +1 I like this answer, plus it's always nice to hide such declarations behind a nicer typedef.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are defining `map` as a variable inside `main`. The definition itself is *kind of* ok, as when the type is parsed the variable has not yet been declared, and `map` in `map<string, int>` is looked up with the common lookup rules, first inside the function, then in the enclosing namespace, and then in the used namespace (`std`) due to the `using namespace std;` line.

After the variable is defined in the first line in main, the identifier `map` refers to the local variable. Basically the compiler sees `map` in `map<string,int>::iterator` and looks it up. It finds the local name `map` that refers to the variable and stops the lookup there. Then it sees the next preprocessor token `<` and parses it as a *less-than* operator, then it finds `string` and it barfs some error message.

You should always keep in mind that C++ lookup for unqualified names starts in the inner context and crawls out from there, but it will stop with the first occurrence of the identifier that you are using. You can solve that by explicitly qualifying identifiers, and that would also solve the issue. Note that `using namespace` is probably not a good hint for someone starting with the language.

```
using namespace std; // <- best remove this algothether
int main() {
   map<string, int> map;
   std::map<string, int>::iterator it = map.begin(); // [1]
}
```

In this modified version, by adding the qualification `std::` before `map` you are hinting the compiler that you don't want the `map` variable in the current context but rather the `map` identifier from the `std` namespace. It would be better if you removed the `using` altogether:

```
int main() {
   std::map<std::string, int> map;
   std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = map.begin();
}
```

And choosing more sensible names for variables might help in avoiding this type of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change variable name from 'map' to 'm', maybe it will help.